# Spark View Engine, Override ${} behaviour

Tags: c#, xml, spark-view-engine

I was wondering if you guys could help me out. I've used the Spark view engine to create my own templating engine which eventually ends up creating an Excel file.

However I've encountered a problem. During this process I push the resultant spark output into an XmlDocument. This causes me problems with illegal characters being produced by spark. For example

```
<foo>
    <bar>${Model.Something}</bar>
</foo>
```

Gets parsed by Spark to produce

```
<foo>
    <bar>This < is a problem</bar>
</foo>
```

So I'm hoping there is someway I can overide the `${}` so that I can deal with the illegal character.

Also please bear in mind that the resultant spark output is a string.

Any thoughts?

Thanks in advance

Comment: How about just using the html encoding that Spark does, have you tried that?  There's a global configuration for it as well as a function all H().  If you need xml encoding (not htnl encoding) you should be able to create a macro and wrap your ouputs with it.

Comment: I've heard about the H method, due to the way I'm using the engine it would seem I don't have access to it. Could you explain your marco concept? bearing in mind that the resultant spark output it a string

Comment: I haven't used Spark the way you are using it, but you should be able to set the global pages automaticEncoding property to true - once you do that all the output should be html encoded by default.  You can then use the special !{} syntax where you don't want the output html encoded.

Comment: Towards the bottom of this page is information on macros: http://sparkviewengine.com/documentation/expressions#Simplecsharpexpressions

Answer (score 1):

[Had](http://sprokhorenko.blogspot.com/2010/08/programming-workarounds.html) same situation, this is the workaround:

```
<!-- Use instead of built-in H() that only works in HTTP context (Html != null) -->
<macro name="H" html="string">${System.Web.HttpUtility.HtmlEncode(html)}</macro>
```

This way you don't need to change your views, you just redefine H() and the do ${H(Model.Something)} as usual.

You can also put this macro into the \Shared_global.spark so that it affects all views.

Comment: Ahh I tried that approach. But in the end I created my own abstract spark view